# ScrollView in editor window never reaches the bottommost items

Tags: unity, c#, gui, editors

```
string searchString;

void OnGUI()
{
    int counter = 0;
    GUI.color = Color.white;
    GUILayout.Space(30);
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachTextField"));
    if (GUILayout.Button("", GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachCancelButton")))
    {
        searchString = "";
        GUI.FocusControl(null);
    }

    GUILayout.Space(25);

    scrollPos =
        EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, false, true,
        GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.Height(position.height));

    foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);
                counter++;
                foreach (UnityEngine.Transform g in item.GameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.Transform>())
                {

                }

                num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);

            num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
            if (counter != gameObjectAndScriptNames.Count)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    GUILayout.EndScrollView();
}
```

The result when I scroll down is there are still items below the bottom of the scroll range.

The farthest I can scroll down is to item 49, and I see half of item 50, but there are 55 items. Why is it not scrolling to the very bottom?

[image: scrolling down not getting to the end]

Answer (score 0):

what is working for me is to remove this part:

```
GUILayout.Height(position.height)
```

from the line:

```
scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, false, true,
            GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.Height(position.height));
```